# Contact Builder mapped using Salesforce Id field (15-digit)

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, contactbuilder

I am currently using Cloud Connect to synchronize Contacts and a related object.

I ran into some issues when attempting query activities to join related records with contacts into a Salesforce DE. I believe some of my queries may be failing due to using the 15-digit Id and not a case safe 18-digit.

Can anyone confirm if they have run into similar issues, and if so, what it entails to correct it?

No emails have been sent to Contacts thus far, so if this is a problem, I am hoping to correct it.  Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

All relationship fields between objects that use Salesforce ID's are auto-converted to the 18-digit versions during the synchronisation process.

In addition, regular Data Extensions actually do not allow storing/importing 15-digit ID's, instead you would get validation errors about `CaseSensitiveSalesforceID`.

Currently there is no way to convert SF ID's from 15 digit to 18 digit in SFMC, this should be done at the source.

It would be easier to help you out if you posted the Query in question.

Comment: Thanks so much for the response. I was actually able to make my query function (albeit handled slightly differently), and all seems to be correct now. As I understand now, Contact ID had nothing to do with the issues I was encountering, but while making the post I was unaware that MC auto-converts to using the 18-digit version of the Contact field "Id" during the initial synchronization setup and mapping it to Contact Key.  I *believe* there is no issue now... at least I hope that is the case.  Thank you again.